# How to split data into train and test, and how to show in figure?

Tags: python-3.x

I have 3176 records. i split into 80% training data and 20% testing data. But I train the following the code.

[image]

this error occurs.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "D:/Python Project/data.py", line 179, in 
>       test_results.append(tests_new[i - 2535])
>   IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Please, add code directly to the question, [not as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/9269043)

Answer (score 0):

```
from sklearn import model_selection
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(train_data, target_data, test_size=0.20)
```

train data: your features list

target data: your predict data

Answer (score 0):

Use try and except block then you will be able to figure out for exactly which index value it is getting error form test_results.append(tests_new[i - 2535]).